# Two dimensional Array List won't compile outside eclipse

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors

I've been having a thousand issues with my code and am not sure what is wrong with it.
This code runs perfectly in the eclipse IDE, but when I take it out to try in `Ready to program java` it prompts me with a compilation error from the following code:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempLayout = new ArrayList<>();
```

and

```
ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<>();
```

Give the errors:

```
Invalid assignment operator

!= expected instead of this token

misplaced construct(s)

Invalid name

Invalid assignment operator

!= expected instead of this token

misplaced construct(s)

Invalid name
```

My environment is Windows 7 running JRE 6 (I must use jre6, I cannot update it)

What is the issue in my code? What should I change so it works?

Comment: "I will set up a bounty for 300 rep on my other stackoverflow account and offer it up to you." --> I'm not too sure this is allowed by SO rules, for one.

Comment: no, I've already been redirected to that question. It's not helped at all

Comment: why not just use your normal SO account?

Comment: Have you noticed that that question says that the diamond operator is only Java 7 and up?

Answer (score 2):

With JDK 6, you haven't the nice syntaxic sugar `ArrayList<>();`.
**JDK 7 has it.**

You have to explicitly declare as following, if you use JDK 6:

```
ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: is this two dimensional? Also, That only answers half the question. I am also still receiving errors

Comment: No, my example is not dealing with multidimensional, but it is the same rule.

Comment: What is your current error?

Comment: `Invalid assignment operator` :(   Right on the `<`

Comment: Post your current code at the bottom of your question or in a Gist.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/WzVMNdCe

Comment: `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempLayout = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`

Comment: That's the same code bob0themighty posted. It's the same result

Comment: Why don't I see it in your gist?

Comment: I added it in after I posted the pastebin

Comment: So please update it, a typo is often made..

Comment: http://pastebin.com/JhrhWV7v I included the full code just in case you find it useful

Comment: Your code compiles with me. Try to clean your whole project and rebuild it

Answer (score 0):

Try including the same type indicator in your new ArrayLists like so:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> tempLayout = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(); 
ArrayList<Integer> row = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: I understand what you are doing, I tested it and I still get very similar errors: `Invalid assignment operator`  etc.... They are on the `<  =  <  (` areas....